# Why is Nhibernate updating my guid?

Tags: nhibernate, guid, updates

My class has a nullable guid property **which is not it's identifier**. The guid is used to group records in a specific way, so that many records can have the same guid.
Everytime I update some other property, nhibernate updates the guid, which is not the desired result.

Here's the mapping:

```
<class name="MyClass" table="SomeTable">
    <id name="Id" column="SomeTableId" type="Int32" >
      <generator class="native">
        <param name="sequence">SomeTableSequence</param>
      </generator>
    </id>
    <property name="Instant" column="Instant" />
    <property name="Value" column="Value" />
    <property name="Description" column="Description" />  
    <property name="Group" column="GroupId" /> <!-- this is the GUID -->
  </class>
```

What should I do to stop this behavior?

**Update**

I forgot to mention that I'm simply doing an ISession.Update call:

```
public void Update(MyClass myInstance) {
    _session.Update(myInstance);
    _session.Flush();
}
```

Comment: Just to make sure, did you check the SQL generated by NHibernate? Maybe the database is updating the column itself? (Just wondering)

Comment: Yes, I did. Nhibernate is sending another value to that column.

Comment: What is the property type and what is the column type? These issues can occur for instance if there is some formatting difference.

Comment: The property is a nullable GUID and the column is a string. It is worth mentioning that it creates, reads and deletes correctly.

Comment: Do you have any triggers/interceptors attached to NHibernate?

Comment: is Equals and GetHashCode correctly implemented on MyClass?

Comment: @SHSE no, there are no triggers/interceptors.

Comment: @Firo MyClass does not implement the equality methods.

Comment: @Fernando, did you mark `GroupId` column as nullable in a database? If so, then create a repo (small console application program that uses NHibernate, SQLite/SqlCe, your model and your mappings). You have to localize the problem. If you could reproduce the problem — post the code.

Comment: Are you saying that you start with a null and the Nhib adds a value? Or do you a valid Guid which then gets changed to another value?

Comment: @fluent I have valid value and then gets changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I didn't have much time available, I ended up doing the update "by hand". I'll gladly accept another answer, if any.